# How can I check if a scene is loaded don't load it again?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Line number 53 in the else :

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

I want that if this scene 0 is already loaded with any other scene in my case there are two scenes only for now but if scene 0 the main menu is already loaded Additive then don't load it again when clicking the escape key.

This script sits in Game scene 1

The problem is if in the main menu I click for a new game and the game scene has loaded but before it removed unloaded the main menu scene and I click escape too fast it will load the main menu scene, again and again, all the time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.GlobalIllumination;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objsToDisable;
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
    public static bool gameSceneLoaded;
    public GameObject fadeImage;
    public Light lights;

    private float volumeLinearToDecibel;

    private void Awake()
    {
        gameSceneLoaded = true;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GetGameMusicVolume();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (Time.timeScale == 0)
            {
                lights.enabled = true;
                DisableEnableUiTexts(true);
                SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(0);
                if (fadeImage != null)
                    fadeImage.SetActive(true);
                GetGameMusicVolume();
                Cursor.visible = false;
                Time.timeScale = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                lights.enabled = false;
                MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame = false;
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneManager_sceneLoaded;
                Cursor.visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SceneManager_sceneLoaded(Scene arg0, LoadSceneMode arg1)
    {
        fadeImage = GameObject.FindWithTag("Game Scene Fader");
        if (fadeImage != null)
            fadeImage.SetActive(false);
        audioMixer.SetFloat("gamemusicvolume", Mathf.Log(0.0001f) * 20);
        DisableEnableUiTexts(false);
        var pauseResumeMainMenuMode = FindInActiveObjectByName("MenuDefaultButtons_Canvas_Pause_Resume");
        var newFreshGameMainMenuMode = FindInActiveObjectByName("MenuDefaultButtons_Canvas_NewFreshGame_SaveGame_Not_Exist");

        newFreshGameMainMenuMode.SetActive(false);
        pauseResumeMainMenuMode.SetActive(true);

        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= SceneManager_sceneLoaded;
    }

    private void DisableEnableUiTexts(bool enabled)
    {
        foreach (GameObject go in objsToDisable)
        {
            if (go.name == "Cameras Control")
            {
                foreach (Transform child in go.transform)
                {
                    if (child.name == "Main Camera")
                    {
                        if (enabled == false)
                        {
                            child.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            child.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                go.SetActive(enabled);
            }
        }
    }

    private float LinearToDecibel(float linear)
    {
        float dB;

        if (linear != 0)
            dB = 20.0f * Mathf.Log10(linear);
        else
            dB = -144.0f;

        return dB;
    }

    private void GetGameMusicVolume()
    {
        volumeLinearToDecibel = LinearToDecibel(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume") / 100f);
        audioMixer.SetFloat("gamemusicvolume", volumeLinearToDecibel);
    }

    GameObject FindInActiveObjectByName(string name)
    {
        Transform[] objs = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Transform>() as Transform[];
        for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (objs[i].hideFlags == HideFlags.None)
            {
                if (objs[i].name == name)
                {
                    return objs[i].gameObject;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the menu object cached already exist open the menu object, if not load the menu scene. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

The more general way would be using [`SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex.html)

> This method will return a valid Scene if a Scene has been added to the build settings at the given build index AND the Scene is loaded. If it has not been loaded yet the SceneManager cannot return a valid Scene.

so simply check [`IsValid`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.IsValid.html) like

```
if(SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(0).IsValid())
```